# Is there a way we can check the Environment variables of a live process?

Tags: windows, debugging, environment-variables

I have a production process that i would like to check its environment variables. Is there a way to check this from a debugger (ollydbg or windbg) or another tool?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) displays the per process environment in one of its property tabs

Comment: yes it does the trick . Thx very much! Just for the info is it possible to access these data from a debugger or another tool ?

Comment: In windbg you can use the !peb extension.